# How to ignore a missing value in a file in a sum in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to get the quantities of some products in 6 Excel file, but in some of them, may not have the product, while in the others has. 
Ex: in the arq1 exists the bj code, but in the arq2 doesn't. So when it makes the sum it doesn't give me the right number. As you can see below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arq1 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Usuario\Downloads\arq1.xlsx')

arq2 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Usuario\Downloads\arq1.xlsx')

list_arq = [arq1,arq2]

i = int(input('Which Arq ? '))

print(bj_xl)

bj_xl = list_arq[i][list_arq[i]['Cod.Artigo']=='PTTGBCH01023']['Unidades']

m_xl = list_arq[i][list_arq[i]['Cod.Artigo']=='PTTGBCM01B05']['Unidades']

b_xl = bj_xl + m_xl

print('B XL:',b_xl)
```

I expect the output to be an integer number but it gave me:

```
Which Arq ? 0
Series([], Name: Unidades, dtype: int64)
B XL: 0    NaN
3    NaN

Name: Unidades, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Apparently, `bj_xl` and `m_xl` have different indexes. When you try to `bj_xl + m_xl`, it tries to match the indexes and can't. Not sure how you want this since you haven't provided a [mcve] , but likely try to sum `bj_xl + m_xl.values`

Comment: I'll try to explain it better and in a clearly way.

My Excel files has 2 columns with many products and their quantities. In the first column it has the product code and in the second column it has the quantities. What happens is that in the file "arq1", I don't have the "bj_xl" code and quantitie, but in the file "arq2" I have. What I'm trying to do is to "say" to Python that, if that product doesn't exist in the file, it should give it a 0 (zero) value, so it won't change my result.

Comment: then use `.add`: `bj_xl.add(m_xl, fill_value=0)`

Answer (score 1):

Try taking the value from the result Series, so that you don't have to worry about index. Assuming `Cod.Artigo` is unique, you can do:

```
bj_xl = list_arq[i][list_arq[i]['Cod.Artigo']=='PTTGBCH01023']['Unidades'].values[0]

m_xl = list_arq[i][list_arq[i]['Cod.Artigo']=='PTTGBCM01B05']['Unidades'].values[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ricky Kim, but when I add the .values(0) to the end, it ends in another error = TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: @kpof94 I added .values[0] not .values(0)